# Troubleshoot Ubuntu 20.04 display freezing

Tags: 20.04, display-manager

Display on Ubuntu 20.04 has been freezing at apparently random moments. Machine under no memory or CPU pressure. Mouse moves, but no input accepted from mouse or keyboard. I have tried:

- Restarting gdm
- Switching to lightdm
- Power cycle

Could anyone help me troubleshoot? Hardware:

- Dell OptiPlex 390 tower PC
- Intel Core i7-2600 CPU @ 3.4GHz
- 16GiB memory
- 931GiB ATA Disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem with gnome sometimes when I do something.
Try to switch to text mode and back to graphical mode (CTRL+ALT+F3 and then CTRL+ALT+F2).

Sometimes gnome just hangs for me, espacially when I use VirtualBox or Copy Paste stuff.

Comment: thanks, did this to restart the display manager when nothing else was responding, and it resolved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue with 12GB of ram.I fixed my freezing issue with memtest86 and found only one RAM working fine.When i removed other rams it worked flawlessly.